# DateTime.TryParse has different behavior on Linux and Windows

Tags: c#, linux, windows, docker, .net-core

I try to understand how DateTime.TryParse works on different environments in .NET Core

Let's say that I call two methods

```
DateTime.TryParse("08-04-2020", new CultureInfo("da-DK"), DateTimeStyles.None, out var res)
DateTime.TryParse("08/04/2020", new CultureInfo("da-DK"), DateTimeStyles.None, out var res)
```

When I run it on Linux (docker) it returns false for first method and true for the second one.
When I run it on Windows it returns true for both methods.

I checked that on Linux default value for CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator in da-DK culture is "/" and probably that's why it returns true only for the second method. But on Windows default value for this separator is "-" so the second method should return false. Why does it return true? it looks like the date separator is taken into account only on Linux env.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but to help you along the way, consider using `TryParseExact`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse): _A custom culture date and time string can be complicated and difficult to parse. The TryParse method attempts to parse a string with several implicit parse patterns, all of which might fail. In contrast, the TryParseExact method requires you to explicitly designate one or more exact parse patterns that are likely to succeed._